# View block - custom ID in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I change id from `block-views-portfolio-view-block` to just:
`portfolio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this to theme's template.php file:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block_html_id'] == "block-views-portfolio-view-block")
    $variables['block_html_id'] = "portfolio";

}
```

and it is working

Answer (score 1):

On the advanced tab in the view settings (on the right side) there will be a "Machine Name" setting. If you were to change it to "portfolio", the id that you'd then see in the HTML would be "view-display-id-portfolio".

I realize that's not exactly what you asked for, but as far as I know, it's the only way to do it within the settings for views. For me though, I prefer it; I often use very general words in it so it can be reused, but I don't want to be SO general as to unintentionally style non-views.

One caveat with this seems to be though: If you make it too long--I'm not sure what the exact number is--such as "view-display-id-thisissomereallylongclassidthatwouldcauseaproblem", it'll chop it down into something like "view-display-id-1237961923", making it almost unusable (it might use a hash to produce it, I dunno.)

The other caveat is that this method is only for a single view display (such as a single block/page/etc.), not every single display of a view, which I think you might have been asking about.

Comment: there is no such thing there

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm actually on vacation, away from the computer and thought I remembered it correctly. I didn't. I realize you went another route and this might not work for you, but I wanted to fill it out for others that might not want/need/know how to theme.